# What can I do to open a specific URL by a controller method?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc

I have a view that show a link, something as:

```
<a href="@Url.Action("Index", "Editing", new { id = Model.Id })"   data-inline="true"  data-mini="true"  data-role="button"  >Torna alla lista</a>
```

The click of this button is handled by the following controller method:

```
public ActionResult Index(long vulnId)
{
    return View();
}
```

This method open a page that have the following URL: `http://localhost:1159/Editing`

What can I do to redirect to the page: `http://localhost:1159/Editing/xxx` where **xxx** is the `vulnId` value?

Comment: You pass that id in the `new { id = Model.Id }`, just match the route parameter name and pass the correct property

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have to do something like this:

```
<a href="@Url.Action("Index", "Editing", new { id = Model.Id })"   data-inline="true"  data-mini="true"  data-role="button"  >Torna alla lista</a>
```

you action parameter name must match what you are passing from `Url.Action` in this case it is **id**:

```
public ActionResult Index(long id)
{
    return View();
}
```

If you want to use **vulnId** then you anchor tag:

```
<a href="@Url.Action("Index", "Editing", new { vulnId = Model.Id })"   data-inline="true"  data-mini="true"  data-role="button"  >Torna alla lista</a>
```

and then action:

```
public ActionResult Index(long vulnId )
    {
        return View();
    }
```